# Print one word multiple times in for-loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

How to print one word or number for multiple times in javascript? e.g. I want to print "1" 10 times, how can I do that?

I am facing this problem and cannot I'm unable to find its solution.

Comment: There is lots of [documentation available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one using a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement).

`n` is the number of times the string is going to be repeated. `w` is what's going to be repeated.

`i < n` is the condition that checks before each iteration of the loop. It'll continue as far as it's `true`. Once, it reaches `10`, it'll stop (since it'll be `false`).

`i++` increments the value of `i` by 1 as far the above condition is `true`.

```js
let n = 10;
let w = "1";
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) console.log(w);
```